# Java Recursive String Compare

Tags: java, java-8

I have to develop a recursive algorithm that checks whether a text pattern and a text match. In the text pattern, the * is a wildcard symbol for any number of arbitrary characters.

Unfortunately I don't know, how to realize if after the wildcard
are different letters.

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Aufgabe4 {
    
    public static boolean isMatching(String pattern, String string) {
        pattern = pattern + ".";
        string = string + ".";

        // End of String
        if(((pattern.charAt(0) == '.') || (pattern.charAt(0) == '*')) && (string.charAt(0) == '.')) return true;

        // Check if the Strings and Pattern are different
        if((pattern.charAt(0) != '*') && (pattern.charAt(0) != string.charAt(0))) return false;


        if(pattern.charAt(0) == '*') return isMatching(pattern, string.substring(1));
        return isMatching(pattern.substring(1), string.substring(1));
    }   
    
    public static void printIsMatching(String pattern, String string) {
        
        System.out.print("Textmuster \"" + pattern + "\" und Text \"" + string + "\" ");
        
        if (isMatching(pattern, string)) {
            System.out.println("passen zusammen.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("passen nicht zusammen.");
        }           
    }   
        
    public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        //System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("Aufgabe4.txt")));
        System.out.println("Ausgabe f�r Aufgabe 4:");

        printIsMatching("","");
        printIsMatching("abc","abc");
        printIsMatching("*","");
        printIsMatching("**","");   
        printIsMatching("*","abc"); 
        printIsMatching("*c","abc");
        printIsMatching("a*c","abbc");
        printIsMatching("a*c","ac");
        printIsMatching("a*c*e","abcde");
        printIsMatching("abc","ab");        
        printIsMatching("abc","abcd");
        printIsMatching("a*c","ab");
        printIsMatching("a*","bcd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a nice exercise! I cannot test it now, but from your description I gather that the `*` is consuming the next character of your `string`. So, I would go into the function tail recursively untill the *next* character of the `pattern` matches the *first* character of the `string`. If there are no more characters in the `string` but still characters in `pattern`, it should return `false`.